# Is it possible to edit your received messages, stored in Inbox or any other Gmail folder, on the fly?

Tags: gmail

I don't care about the headers getting corrupted or keeping anything intact for forensic purposes.  I need to edit a bunch of messages for brevity so that they are more convenient to work with later, while keeping them in the Inbox.

Answer (score 2):

No.

I can think of two alternatives.

You can reply/forward the messages to yourself (after editing the reply). If you change the subject you can "break" the conversation (or simply delete the original message after your reply/forward).

The other is to set up an IMAP client to your Gmail mailbox. Some of those will allow for editing messages already received.

Comment: Thanks.  Replying/forwarding is not an option, because of the sheer volume of incoming emails that need to undergo the editing.  Do you know any IMAP clients that will allow this?  I don't think Thunderbird or Outlook can.

Comment: No, sorry. I haven't used a desktop email client in a long time. You might ask at [softwarerecs.se].